# JQuery remove hyperlink and replace with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I remove a hyperlink from a li and replace it with some other text?

```
<li class="pull-left">
     <a href="#" class="js-close-post" data-post-id="1">
       Close
     </a>
 </li>
```

The following removes the entire li. What I want is to fade out the link and fade in with the text `Closed`

```
<li class="pull-left">
    Closed

 </li>

  $(".js-close-post").click(function (e) {
        var link = $(e.target);
        link.parents("li").fadeOut(function () {
             $(this).remove();
        });

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can jQuery [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) for this.

```js
  $(".js-close-post").click(function (e) {
        var link = $(e.target);
        $a = $(this);
        $a.parents("li").fadeOut(function () {
             $a.replaceWith($a.text());
        }).fadeIn();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pull-left">
     <a href="#" class="js-close-post" data-post-id="1">
       Close
     </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Note ... *"replace it with some other text"*

Answer (score 3):

Using `text('Closed')` or `html('Closed')` on the `<li>` would remove the `<a>`

Try

```
$(".js-close-post").click(function (e) {  
     // "this" is the <a>      
     var $li = $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(function () {              
          $li.text('Closed').fadeIn();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(".js-close-post").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var closedElement = parent.append("Closed").hide();    
        closedElement.fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/noLscfh9/